# Measuring angles (not lat long) in QGIS in DMS

Tags: qgis

I'm just wanting to find out if QGIS has a setting to measure angles (using the measurement tool) in Degrees Minutes Seconds. Similarly, if one could input Degrees Minutes Seconds using the CAD Tools toolbar?

I am using QGis 3.0

Not sure if I'm just missing a setting somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: what version of QGIS

Comment: I am using QGis 3.0. I'll amend my question and ad it there too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Measurement tool units settings are available under Settings menu > Options > Map tools. The options for angle units are:

- Degrees
- Radians
- Gons/gradians
- Minutes of arc
- Seconds of arc
- Turns/revolutions

Degrees Minutes Seconds isn't one of the options.

You can [request](https://issues.qgis.org) this feature be added to the next version of QGIS.